# Loading Image to Custom List Array - Malformed Exception Protocol Not Found Error

Tags: java, android

It works fine when I set myFileURL as "http://www.google.com/someimage.jpg", but when I try to use a variable I receive the error mesage.

My code is here: http://pastebin.com/QTHwu5tv

**Solution**
I was loading the data from an array result in a JSON query which added the brackets to the results.

Comment: 10-18 12:49:36.094: WARN/System.err(1179): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: ["http://192.168.1.5/u/pic/2011/10/11/ytbtbrevfcecffr.jpg"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution I was loading the data from an array result in a JSON query which added the brackets to the results.

Answer (score 0):

after looking at your log. you need to provide a protocol for the file to download.

Try appending `http://` at the beginning image path. it will be able to download then.

Comment: Oops it must of not copied right, but I did have http:// in front of the server IP address.

Comment: i suggest you to log the url you are requesting, then you know what exactly you are requesting for.

Comment: Log the variable or the URL object?  Also when I set the variable manually it works fine.

Comment: may be both, to be on the safer side.

Comment: u can log anything by using object.toString()

Comment: I've noticed if I create an array with URLs it will work fine, but if I try to use an array that has data loaded in it from a JSON respone array thats when I have the problem.